# I added buttons to a frame but they still won't show up

Tags: java, button, jframe, jpanel

I'm writing a program that does the following:
Create a frame and set its layout to FlowLayout. 
 * Create two panels and add them to the frame. 
 * Each panel contains three buttons. The panel uses FlowLayout. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Flow{

  public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Testing out these JPanels");
    f.setSize(400, 100); 
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JButton b = new JButton("button 1");
    JButton butt = new JButton("button 2");
    JButton bug = new JButton("button 3");
    JButton button = new JButton("button 4");
    JButton button5 = new JButton("button 5");
    JButton button6 = new JButton("button 6");
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    p.setVisible(true);
    p.setSize(200, 100);
    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
    pnl.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    pnl.setSize(200,100);
    p.add(b);
    p.add(butt);
    p.add(bug);
    pnl.add(button5);
    pnl.add(button);
    pnl.add(button6);
    f.add(button5);

  }
}
```

When I run the program, the frame shows up but not my buttons or panels. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `JPanel` `p` and `pnl` to `JFrame`

```
 //  f.add(button5); Comment this line button5 is already added to pnl

 // Now add the two panel with JFrame.
  f.add(p);
  f.add(pnl);
```

And, for proper layout manager, go through this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add you JPanel to your JFrame

```
  f.getcontentpane().add(p);
  f.getcontentpane().add(pnl);
```

and then call setVisible() on the frame.

```
f.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not showing because you set the visibility of frame to `true` before you add the buttons, therefore it only rendered the frame without buttons and by the time you re-size the JFrame it will show the buttons because it is rendered again.

**solution:**

set the visibility of the frame after you add the buttons

```
  JFrame f = new JFrame("Testing out these JPanels");
  f.setSize(400, 100); 
  f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
  f.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
  f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  JButton b = new JButton("button 1");
  JButton butt = new JButton("button 2");
  JButton bug = new JButton("button 3");
  JButton button = new JButton("button 4");
  JButton button5 = new JButton("button 5");
  JButton button6 = new JButton("button 6");
  JPanel p = new JPanel();
  p.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  p.setVisible(true);
  p.setSize(200, 100);
  JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
  pnl.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  pnl.setSize(200,100);
  p.add(b);
  p.add(butt);
  p.add(bug);
  pnl.add(button5);
  pnl.add(button);
  pnl.add(button6);
  f.add(button5);
  f.setVisible(true); //relocated here
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created the panels, but have forgot to add the panels in that frame, exactly the same way you have added the "button 5"

try including this in code:

```
f.add(p);
f.add(pnl);
```